# How would I get rid of or significantly reduce the timing difference in a password checker?

Tags: python, string-comparison

My teacher gave us a segment of code and he wants us to alter it so that the execution time of the code (password checker) is either a) eliminated (fixed) or b) significantly reduced.

EDIT: We just learned about counting the number of characters in a string. So I think what he wants is if someone were to input "1941abab", it would take longer for the program to check if it is correct or not because the first 5 characters are the same as the correct answer. He wants that delay in checking to be slower.

```
s1 = input("Enter Passcode:")
if s1 == "1941abcd":
    print("welcome")
else:
    print("denied")
```

Comment: What does that mean? There's nothing in the code you've shared that would cause a meaningful delay. (You also haven't asked a question. You've just told us what you need to do. Please read [ask]. The clearer you can be, the better. We can't help unless we understand the question.)

Comment: I highly doubt that a beginners' programming course is going to involve the student improving on the performance of Python's built in string comparison...

Comment: I doubt this is the code your professor gave to you with that question in mind. It's a pointless question then

Comment: I think either you've misunderstood the requirement or the assignment doesn't make sense. I mean, you could try compare the hash of the strings, rather than rely on character comparisons but I'd be surprised if it was faster, and I think it would be the same complexity

Comment: This makes no sense from more than one reason. You cant even measure the time execution, beacuse the execution time is SO close to zero, that if you save that time execution into variable and compare it like this time_execution == 0, it will return True. No joking

Comment: @Martin and others: The delay difference, while very small, is measurable (definitely locally, and sometimes even over a network connection), meaningful, and exploitable. It's called a [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack), which is one of many types of [side-channel attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack), and making a constant-time password checker is a perfectly reasonable exercise in an introductory security class.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to compare strings is to compare one pair of characters at a time: compare the first character of the first string with the first character of the second string, and then the second characters, then the third, and so on. Once you find a pair that doesn't match, you know *without examining the rest of the string* that the strings are not equal. If all the pairs are equal, the strings are equal. As an additional optimization, you can start out by comparing the lengths of the strings - if they're not the same length, they're not equal, and you don't even need to compare characters.

That likely what `==` does, and the security problem is the speed optimization where it stops comparing once it finds a pair that doesn't match. The attacker can try the passwords `axxx`, `bxxx`, `cxxx`, and so on, and once they try `1xxx`, they will notice that the comparison takes a little more time because `==` will now check the second character pair too because the first character pair matched. Now they know that the first character of the password is `1`. Solution: always compare *all* the character pairs, even after you've determined that the strings are not equal (and don't compare the length of the strings; always make as many character comparisons as there are characters in the supplied password - in short, try not to reveal any information about the actual password).

Comment: Yes, we just learned about == and all the different conversions you can do to a string. I think what my professor is asking is if I were to enter the wrong password, it would take longer to process it if the first couple characters were the same as the correct answer. He wants that execution time to be nonexistent or reduced no matter the number of characters lining up.

Comment: From curiosity, are we really talking about timeframes here that can give indicative results? Also, doesn't this fall apart when you hash passwords properly rather than store plaintext? I'm curious about how much of an attack vector this is.

Comment: @SophieHarrison: the _difference_ in execution time should be as small as possible.

Comment: @roganjosh: This is a well-established kind of [side-channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack) called a [timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack). While the difference in execution time is small, it is still measurable, sometimes even over a network connection.

Comment: @roganjosh: Hash comparisons are also vulnerable to some extent: you don't need to figure out the "real" password, you just need to figure out a string that produces the same hash. Make some random strings until you have found one whose hash starts with `0`, one with `1`, and so on up to `f`, and see which one gets rejected slightly more slowly than the others. You now have the first character of the hash, e.g. `8`. Then, find strings that hash to `8a`, `8b`, and so on, and try those.

Comment: @roganjosh: (Of course, finding candidate strings becomes harder and harder the more characters you have, but this still lets you figure out quite a few characters of the hash quite easily, and then you can perhaps guess the password via a rainbow table.)

Comment: Thanks, you've given me plenty to research :)

Comment: @roganjosh: You're welcome! :-) Here's an article about a timing attack on the AES encryption algorithm across a network connection: https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf.